# Equivalent to Meetup.com without public lists of event members

Tags: web-apps, meetings

I am looking for a web application where:

- People can join and leave a group without moderator approval, but with email verification
- I can create events for the group and people can sign up to participate
- I can add and remove members from events
- I can freeze the event so that no new members can join
- Members do not see who else has joined the event unless I toggle that information to be public
- Ability to email all group members

What I'm looking for is similar to Meetup.com, except that what I'm looking for is a little more private. So far as I know, Meetup.com can make it so that a group is private in that non-members do not see event information. But what Meetup can't do is make it so that people who have applied to an event are not visible. Put another way, people on Meetup who sign up to an event are always visible to other members signing up for the event. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there an online app that does what I am looking for?